# Problems using my JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, repaint

I am making a graphical interface in Netbeans where you can put a series of numbers (example: 7 8 5 4 10 13) in the textfield "punten" and when you press the button "ververs" a graphical linechart of all the numbers should appear (in my panel). I made a class "Gui" that extends JFrame with the Textfield, the button and a panel in it. I also made a class "Grafiek" that extends JPanel and that is linked with the panel in my "Gui". The chart would be on the JPanel that is displayed in my JFrame.

The problems that I experience are: the repaint(); command won't go to the paintComponent(Graphics g)-method and my private variables won't change (the length of punt and punti stays 1 no matter what variables I put in my Textbox).

Can somebody please help me, I've been working on this project for days.

My Gui-class:

```
package grafiek;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Gui extends javax.swing.JFrame {

private Grafiek newJPanel;

/**
 * Creates new form Gui
 */
public Gui() {
    initComponents();
    newJPanel = new Grafiek();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    punten = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    fout = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    javax.swing.JButton ververs = new javax.swing.JButton();
    panel = new Grafiek();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    fout.setText("j");

    ververs.setText("Ververs");
    ververs.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            verversActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    panel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0), 2));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout panelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panel);
    panel.setLayout(panelLayout);
    panelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    panelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 195, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addComponent(panel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(punten, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(ververs)
                    .addGap(6, 6, 6)
                    .addComponent(fout)
                    .addGap(0, 302, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(punten, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(panel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(fout)
                .addComponent(ververs))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void verversActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    newJPanel.verwerkData(punten.getText());
}                                       

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Gui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Gui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Gui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Gui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Gui().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel fout;
private javax.swing.JPanel panel;
private javax.swing.JTextField punten;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

My Grafiek-class:

```
package grafiek;

import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Grafiek extends javax.swing.JPanel {

private String[] punt;
private int[] punti;
private int afstandX, afstandY, puntX1, puntY1, puntX2, puntY2;
private int max;

/**
 * Creates new form Grafiek
 */
public Grafiek() {
    initComponents();
    punt = new String[1];
    punti = new int[1];
    afstandX = 0;
    afstandY = 0;
    puntX1 = 0; 
    puntY1 = 0; 
    puntX2 = 0; 
    puntY2 = 0;
    max = 1;
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    for(int i=0; i<punti.length; i++) {
        if(max <= punti[i]) {
            max = punti[i];
        }
    }

    afstandX = getWidth()/punt.length;
    afstandY = getHeight()/max;

    for(int i=0; i<punti.length; i++) {
        puntX1 = puntX2;
        if(i == 0) {
            puntY1 = getHeight();
        }
        else puntY1 = puntY2;
        puntX2 += afstandX;
        puntY2 = getHeight() - punti[i]*afstandY;

        g.drawLine(puntX1, puntY1, puntX2, puntY2);
    }

    puntX2 = 0;
}

public void verwerkData(String s) {
    punt = s.split(" ");

    punti = new int[punt.length];

    for(int i=0; i<punt.length; i++) {
        punti[i] = Integer.parseInt(punt[i]);
    }

    repaint();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see is that you have declare an instantiated

```
newJPanel = new Grafiek();
```

which is the object that you call in the action method

```
private void verversActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    newJPanel.verwerkData(punten.getText());
}
```

But the `newJPanel` is never added to the frame. The object that looks like it is being added to the frame is

```
panel = new Grafiek();
```

which is in the `initComponents()`. Try changing

```
newJPanel.verwerkData(punten.getText());
```

to

```
panel.verwerkData(punten.getText());
```

And get rid of the `newJpanel` because you never use it